# Start mp3 playback via shell command on raspberry pi

Tags: php, html, shell, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a raspberry pi, I put an apache server on it and a loud speaker is connected to it as well.

What I am trying to do is to make the raspberry play some set of music by clicking on certain button on the html webpage.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-" />
    <title>Sons</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Voici les son que le cone est capable de produire:<br />
    <ul>
            <li>Chien</li>
<form method="post" action=""
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" value="Poster"/>
    </p>
</form>
            <li>Alarme</li>

            <li>Buzzer</li>
    </ul>

    <p/>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['exec']))
    {

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='yes')
            {
            $cmd=exec(escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/mpg123 /var/www/html/chien.mp3'));
            $cmd=exec(escapeshellcmd('mv /var/www/html/test.txt     /var/www/html/images/'));

    if(!$cmd)
    {
            echo "C'est bon";
    }
    else
    {
            echo "Nope";
    }
    }
    }

echo '<form method="post" action="Son.php?action=yes">
<input type="submit" name="exec" value="Executer">
</form>';
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

So I use mpg123 to play music on the raspberry, it is working just fine when I just type the command in the shell but it does not in the PHP part.

The weird part is that the command mv which just move a .txt file is actually working while the other does not.

Thank you for helping me, I don't really know what to do at this point, I just began learning HTML & PHP so I am still kind of confused.

Comment: Your problem does not seem to be in executing a shell command. I suggested the new title.

Comment: I think this command `mpg123 chien.mp3` needs to exit in order to load the PHP page correctly. try to put an & at the end. `mpg123 chien.mp3&`  to run end immediately exit.

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping.Adding an & at the end does not change anything. What should I put in the title ?

Comment: Try specifying the full path to the file, e.g. `mpg123 /var/www/chien.mp3` or wherever it is. Also check the error logs to see if it's failing for permission reasons.

Comment: I tried the full path and it is still the same problem, also I checked the error_log file from apache2 and there is no permision errors.

Comment: another idea would be to put in the full path to the mpg123 executable as well...

Comment: The full path to the command is /usr/bin/mpg123 right ? If it is then it does not change the problem.

Comment: You can find out by typing `which mpg123` on a shell prompt on the pi. /usr/bin/mpg123 sounds reasonable

Anyway there should be some output in the logs of apache or php, you may also try using mv -v ... on the second command (make the move verbose) to help locating it

Comment: which mpg123 shows /usr/bin/mpg123. the file /var/log/apache2/error.log does not show any error that could stop the command. I'm not sure you're trying to do by adding -v to the second command. This one works and do what I want . But adding -v gave me: « /var/www/html/test.txt » -> « /var/www/html/images/test.txt »

Answer (score 0):

I am new to PHP too but perhaps you are overwriting the first command with the second because they use the same variable name? Or is $CMD the return value of the command?

Comment: Yeah cmd has nothing to do with the shell command, I just did that because I wanted to know if the program actually uses those instructions. I tried with one line, and It wasn't working.